# Non-symmetric PROPs

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, terminology

Roughly speaking, a colored [PROP](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/PROP) is a category in which there are morphisms $x_1,\dotsc,x_n \to y_1,\dotsc,y_m$ with multiple input and output objects. It seems to me that all authors also assume actions of the symmetric groups, so that these should actually be called symmetric PROPs. (This is similar to the convention that topologists mean symmetric [operads](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/operad) when they write operads.) Have non-symmetric PROPs been studied in the literature? Or do they have another name? (After all, the last P stands for permutation.) Also, is there a special name for colored PROPS, as there is for colored operads ([multicategories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/multicategory))? What about "bimulticategories"? The notion of a [polycategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/polycategory) seems to be more restrictive. Or do people usually mean the colored version anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-symmetric version is PROs. The colors versions are just called colored. Polycategories are indeed more restrictive.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a reference beyond the short n-lab article https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/PRO ?

Comment: I'm not sure. You might try to start from the references in PROP.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find anything there.

Comment: There's a little bit in Leinster's book on higher operads, higher categories.

Comment: Thank you! The original reference seems to be: *Homotopy Invariant Algebraic Structures on Topological Spaces* by Boardman and Vogt. LNM Vol. 347 (1973).

Comment: Now I am confused: Leinster shows in Prop. 2.3.1 that PROs are equivalent to multicategories. So this is a different notion of PRO I wanted here (namely, multiple outputs).

Comment: Yes, I'm confused too: I'm not sure why Leinster requires this quasi-Cartesian property.